# Почему такая сортировка?

Tags: python, бот, discord, disnake

Сортирую по полю `last_battle_time` (timestamp - Время последнего боя).

Простой код метода:

````py
async def send_session_embed(self, ctx, session):
        try:
            start_time = session["start_time"].strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
            account_id = session["account_id"]
            nickname = session["nickname"]
 
            main_embed = disnake.Embed(
                title=f"От: {start_time}\nСессия для: `{nickname} | {account_id}`",
            )
 
            max_tanks_to_show = 10
 
            if "tanks_stats" in session:
                stats = session["tanks_stats"]
                player_data = self.api.get_player_technique_stats(session["account_id"])
 
                total_battles = 0
                total_wins = 0
                total_damage = 0
 
                tank_info_list = []
                for tank_id, saved_stats in stats.items():
                    tank_data = next((tank_info["all"] for tank_info in player_data if str(tank_info["tank_id"]) == tank_id), None)
 
                    if tank_data:
                        current_battles = tank_data.get('battles', 0)
                        current_wins = tank_data.get('wins', 0)
                        current_damage_dealt = tank_data.get('damage_dealt', 0)
                        last_battle_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(tank_data.get('last_battle_time', 0), tz=timezone.utc)
 
                        saved_battles = saved_stats["battles"]
                        saved_wins = saved_stats["wins"]
                        saved_damage_dealt = saved_stats["damage_dealt"]
                        saved_last_battle_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(
                            saved_stats.get("last_battle_time", 0), tz=timezone.utc)
 
                        if (current_battles > saved_battles or
                            current_wins > saved_wins or
                            current_damage_dealt > saved_damage_dealt or
                                last_battle_time > saved_last_battle_time):
 
                            delta_battles = current_battles - saved_battles
                            delta_wins = current_wins - saved_wins
                            delta_damage = current_damage_dealt - saved_damage_dealt
 
                            win_rate = (delta_wins / delta_battles) * 100 if delta_battles != 0 else 0
                            avg_damage = round(delta_damage / delta_battles) if delta_battles > 0 else 0
 
                            total_battles += delta_battles
                            total_wins += delta_wins
                            total_damage += delta_damage
 
                            try:
                                tank_info = await self.get_tank_info_embed(tank_id)
                                tank_name = tank_info['name']
                                print(f"Информация о танке {tank_id} из get_tank_info_embed: {tank_info}")
                            except Exception as e:
                                tank_name = "Неизвестный танк"
                                print(f"Ошибка при получении информации о танке {tank_id}: {e}")
 
                            tank_info_list.append({
                                "name": tank_name,
                                "win_rate": win_rate,
                                "avg_damage": avg_damage,
                                "battles": delta_battles,
                                "last_battle_time": last_battle_time
                            })
 
                win_rate = (total_wins / total_battles) * 100 if total_battles != 0 else 0
                avg_damage = total_damage // total_battles if total_battles > 0 else 0
 
                main_embed.add_field(
                    name="",
                    value=f"```css\nБоев: {total_battles}\nПП: {win_rate:.2f}%\nСр. урон: {avg_damage}```",
                    inline=False
                )
 
                if tank_info_list:
                    sorted_tank_info_list = sorted(
                        tank_info_list, key=lambda x: x["last_battle_time"], reverse=True)
 
                    for tank_info in sorted_tank_info_list[:max_tanks_to_show]:
                        tank_name = tank_info["name"]
                        win_rate = tank_info["win_rate"]
                        avg_damage = tank_info["avg_damage"]
                        battles = tank_info["battles"]
 
                        tank_info_str = f"**{tank_name}**\n```css\nПП: {win_rate:.2f}% Урон: {avg_damage} Бои: {battles}```"
 
                        main_embed.add_field(
                            name="", value=tank_info_str, inline=False)
 
                total_tanks = len(tank_info_list)
                if total_tanks > max_tanks_to_show:
                    main_embed.set_footer(text=f"Показано {max_tanks_to_show} из {total_tanks} танков")
 
                await ctx.send(embed=main_embed)
            else:
                await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(description="Сыграйте хотя бы один бой, чтобы посмотреть сессию!"))
 
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f"Произошла ошибка при отправке сессии: {e}")
````

Выводит информацию в ембед так:

[image: Как выводит]

Но как правильно:

[image: Правильный порядок]

Comment: Выведите в эмбед само время последнего боя. Там нормальные даты? Они верно упорядочены?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, поправил, проблема была в том, что время получалось из апи отдельным полем. Была только tank_data, которая получала all.

Надо было [так](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1218683881193082951/1222604444928053258/image.png?ex=6616d21e&is=66045d1e&hm=31e19152e636e99fec8df3bf942bd87e1e1e9b6e1707623b82923da47cba1676&) сделать в embed для наглядности. А в коде вышло [так](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1221084628039766047/1222605933331484703/image.png?ex=6616d381&is=66045e81&hm=e9439b3454e37928e93c294de7b2c36d86fa07c701a28f8d4b4939e82349f2aa&)